# php method undefined in protobuf generated class

Tags: php, grpc, daml

I am writing a client app to connect to the DA sandbox.  The following code:

```
$grpc_channel = Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure();
    $client = new Com\Digitalasset\Ledger\Api\V1\LedgerIdentityServiceClient('localhost:7600', [
        'credentials' => $grpc_channel,
    ]);
    $request = new Com\Digitalasset\Ledger\Api\V1\GetLedgerIdentityRequest();
    $ledger_id_response = $client->GetLedgerIdentity($request);
    $ledger_id = $ledger_id_response->getLedgerId();
```

causes the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Grpc\UnaryCall::getLedgerId() in /.../damlprojects/loaner_car/php/ledger_client.php:31
```

However, it should be defined since $ledger_id_response is of type GetLedgerIdentityResponse which does have a method:

```
public function getLedgerId()
{
    return $this->ledger_id;
}
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: are you certain that `Grpc\UnaryCall` is the correct namespace/scope?

Comment: Where can I look at the source for the code?

Answer (score 1):

Is that an unary call? You haven't received the response yet. $ledger_id_response is null so far.

```
$call = $client->GetLedgerIdentity($request);
list($ledger_id_response, $status) = $call->wait();
if ($status->code == \Grpc\STATUS_OK) {
  $ledger_id = $ledger_id_response->getLedgerId();
}
```

Comment: I don't know how it works but it does work.  Do you have a question only on my code or also on the grpc hello world example as well?

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reviewing the 'client code' in the hello world example on [grpc's website](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php.html#update-the-client)

```
$request = new Helloworld\HelloRequest();
$request->setName($name);
list($reply, $status) = $client->SayHello($request)->wait();
```

I realized my mistakes.
1. When making a request for a service.  It must be done by calling wait() on the return object.  Therefore

```
$client->GetLedgerIdentity($request);
```

must be changed to

```
$client->GetLedgerIdentity($request)->wait();
```

2.The return value comes in the form of an array.  Therefore

```
$ledger_id_response = must be changed to

list($ledger_id_response, $status) =
```

like this

```
list($ledger_id_response, $status) = $client->GetLedgerIdentity($request)->wait();
```

Now getLedgerId can be called

```
$ledger_id = $ledger_id_response->getLedgerId();
```

without errors!